# gorilla websocket example with a superfluous channel?

Tags: go, websocket, channel, gorilla

I don't understand the reason for the channel "done", in this simple example

https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/master/examples/echo/client.go

the channel is type of struct and three times used

1. Z41 defer close(done)
2. Z57 case <-done:
3. Z77 case <-done:

Nobody writes into the channel. So 2. and 3. will block,
as far as I can remember. I would be grateful for any explanation
how this works.

Comment: Please put all relevant code directly in your question. Links inevitably die over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [specification says](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Close):

> After calling close, and after any previously sent values have been received, receive operations will return the zero value for the channel's type without blocking.

The `case <-done:` branches do not block after `close(done)` is called.

It's common to use channel close to signal completion because the goroutine that signals completion does not need to know the number of goroutines that wait on completion.  Also, channel close will never block waiting for a receiver.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation